# power shell on target machine in VSO

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

'Power shell on target machine' step in VSO is displaying logs only after step completes. Is there any way that I can see logs while this step is running?
Whatever i wrote 'Write-verbose' notes are displaying only after step is completed.

Answer (score 0):

With built-in **PowerShell on target machine** task, you can’t get the log while remote script is running.

Source code:

```
  $deploymentResponse = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $RunPowershellJob -ArgumentList $machine, $scriptPath, $resourceProperties.winrmPort, $scriptArguments, $initializationScriptPath, $resourceProperties.credential, $resourceProperties.protocolOption, $resourceProperties.skipCACheckOption, $enableDetailedLoggingString, $sessionVariables, $PSScriptRoot 
    Write-ResponseLogs -operationName $deploymentOperation -fqdn $displayName -deploymentResponse $deploymentResponse 

####################################################

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $RunPowershellJob -ArgumentList $machine, $scriptPath, $resourceProperties.winrmPort, $scriptArguments, $initializationScriptPath, $resourceProperties.credential, $resourceProperties.protocolOption, $resourceProperties.skipCACheckOption, $enableDetailedLoggingString, $sessionVariables, $PSScriptRoot 
$Jobs.Add($job.Id, $resourceProperties) 
...
Write-ResponseLogs -operationName $deploymentOperation -fqdn $displayName -deploymentResponse $output
```

The workaround is that you can call Invoke-Command through **PowerShell** task:

```
$p=ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$mc=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("username",$p)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName [machine] -FilePath "hello.ps1" -Credential $mc
```